# .NET ESB with Mapping support

Tags: .net, biztalk, nservicebus, esb

We are building an enterprise integration system, and are in the active process of evaluating some .NET ESBs. We interface with a number of external systems - which exposes data via a wide range of protocols - mainly http post, http get, TCP/IP, Webservice, Meessage Queue. So, we need sync and async mapping support for these systems.

Biztalk + ESB Toolkit is one option - Would like to hear further options?

We had a look at NServiceBus and Masstransit as well - The problem with the likes of NServiceBus and MassTransit requires development of custom adapters for pumping the messages back and forth. There is no out of the box functionality available for mapping with external services.

Comment: I expect that Windows Server AppFabric (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849) will replace BizTalk sometime in the future. The ESB market is under control by the "Java" supporters, so Microsoft have to get a good starting position with the Cloud (Azure) instead of looking behind. With Server AppFabric the first step is done. But it's not a drop in replacement for ESB toolkit right now. It's designed for WCF developers who do not care about orchestration, transformation, mediation etc. It's a simple entry point for all those starting with WS-* as interoperability protocol.

Comment: BizTalk is a broker, regardless of what you put on top of it. That being said, maybe what you need is a broker and not an Enterprise Service Bus.

Comment: @Udi I'm talking about Biztalk + ESB toolkit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/dd876606

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use BizTalk + NService Bus?
http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/architecture/nservicebus-and-biztalk
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=b57b7625-7316-4f56-b88e-1fb685efae5b

Answer (score 2):

For the integration part (multi protocol support) you could use either BizTalk or WCF, but BizTalk has the most comprehensive set of connectors for different technologies.

For mapping, the BizTalk mapper (or another graphical tool) will work for **simple cases**, but these tools quickly lead to very complex maps (hard to develop/read/modify), for cases with even  minor sources of complexity. So you should also look at another solution for mapping, such as XSLT.

For the ESB part, I would avoid the ESB Toolkit, because it's a complex, immature and fragile framework, so using it in a project is risky and will probably lead to a more complex solution.

NServiceBus would seem like a better solution and can fit nicely with BizTalk for the integration part.

Comment: +1 - BizTalk is ideal for EAI and good at Business Process, but cumbersome for mass ESB connectivity. Just to clarify - the Biztalk mapper is just a visualizer for an underlying XSLT map - you can use native XSLT if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out the Enterprise Integration Patterns book (http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/), which has the messaging approach to enterprise integration, as offered with many service busses.

Just as a note, you should consider splitting the sync and async operations, as you probably don't want to use messaging for sync operations. They do fit async operations perfectly. It could be the case, that you will benefit from more than one approach, depending on your setup (like NServiceBus and WCF).